# Matching /comparing a Database Field using a Key with different **combination** in Mysql 5.0

Tags: mysql, performance, search, optimization, query-optimization

I have a **table: db_details** in **MYSQL 5.0** with a Table field: **Description** having **10,0000 entries** . I want an **optimum** method to **search** a **key** and get the result with different **combination**.For example:

Let the 4 entries of **description** [actually its **10000**] field is as follows:

description 1 : I want to see my **friend**

description 2: My **friend** has a red **pen** and yellow **box**

description 3: This yellow **box** belongs to my **friend**

description 4: He is a doctor

I want to compare these with a **key : pen box friend** and should get result in the **order**: first **description 2**, then **description 3** and then **description 1** [Its because description 2 has the max hit ,then description 3 and so on]

please help me. I want to know how it should be done..Since it is a **Huge** database ,i want to get this without a **delay** whether by using page offset or not.

Comment: Naturally, you haven't optimized your MySQL instance, nor have you told us what **storage engine** you use. Software runs on hardware. Unless you allow software to use that hardware optimally, no "method" will yield performance. Also, 100k rows is not huge, it's tiny. Please include *what you've tried* and what configuration for MySQL you use and what hardware it runs on.

Comment: I read the table from database and did linq operation on it(       var searchTerms = Comparate.Split(' ');
var results = inputs
    .GroupBy(sentence => sentence.Split(' '))
    .Where(grouping => searchTerms.Intersect(grouping.Key).Any())
    .OrderByDescending(grouping => grouping.Key.Count())
    .SelectMany(grouping => grouping);  i coudnt find any query to do the above operation in mysql 5.0.100k seems to be small for u..But the current method is consuming enough time..if please tell me the solution for this problem

Comment: It's consuming time because your database is **not configured properly**. 100k rows is small because it doesn't take that much space and can fit into RAM, making it fast to work with. Please, read carefully what I wrote and don't just dump some text on me here to decypher. Try to understand what I told you. Configure your database so it can make use of your hardware (RAM) and then it will be fast. You haven't said what configuration you use, what storage engine you use and what hardware it runs on.

Comment: I am using laptop [i5] and engine is innodb..i dont know much about the configuration and all..Its not matter of decyphering..it just bcos i am not getting the result..

Comment: By default, InnoDB uses 8 megabytes of RAM. Database admins tend to use a lot of ram, like 85% - 90% of what the server has. Variable to control how much ram is used is called `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. If you have about 2 gigs of ram free, I suggest you edit your `my.cnf`, find the section `[innodb]` and add `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G`. Save the file, restart mysql, run your query again.

Comment: @N.B., u said is right. But my current problem is how to convert that linq to mysql query.,..or can u give me another query which suits my requirement..i have posted another question regarding that..Pls do help me..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038051/how-can-i-convert-my-query-from-linq-to-mysql

Comment: @N.B., i am behind this for many days..i cant get the real answer..The query in linq is taking plenty of time..so i thought it woud be same in mysql..ut u gave a solution to improve the performance in mysql..But i neither dont know to query the required in mysql5.0 in effective way nor to optimize the query in linq..he do help me..whatever may be the method,please consider this help request

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, i think [Shpinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is more suitable for do this job.

Sphinx is much faster and you can set priority of results.

Comment: In my case, i can get results only in 0.02s. Even table includes about 30 million rows!

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1 : create table description(descr TEXT,fulltext(descr));

STEP 2 : insert into description values('I want to see my friend'),('My friend has a red pen and yellow box'),('This yellow box belongs to my friend'),('He is a doctor');

STEP 3 : select * from description where match(descr) against('pen box friend');

Output is as follows : (as you required in order)

My friend has a red pen and yellow box

This yellow box belongs to my friend

I want to see my friend

Note: But it will be comparatively slow as compared to sphinx.

Comment: Include sources that can back up your statements about being slow compared to sphinx. Include *why*. If you don't, it's not a fact, it's just your opinion - making the answer pointless.

Comment: Full Text is not a type in Mysql 5.0.